# Populate new ID Column with Sequential Identifiers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to populate a column nvarchar(12) with a unique sequence starting at "PM1000000000" and increment by 1 for each row. There is no identity column or Primary key (edit) to loop around which makes this problem quite challenging as most of the example I found use an identity column to loop around

I found an example, example 3 on MSDN at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/111401 but it doesn't show incrementing a row

Can anyone help me populate this field so that I can make this a primary key? Note: this table has 60 million rows but I'm open to any ideas at this point to just get this working

Comment: So the `ID` always starts with `PM` then loops from `1000000000` to `9999999999`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT
    ID = 'PM' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + 1000000000 - 1)
FROM <YourTable>
```

---

**`UPDATE`** Statement

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = 'PM' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + 1000000000 - 1)
    FROM TestData
)
UPDATE Cte SET ID = RN
```

Comment: Thx but this just selects the records..  I need to update the rows with the ID created

Comment: Just transform it to an `UPDATE` statement then.

Comment: Converted to update but then you get:
 Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

Comment: My table doesn't have a Primary key or Identity column. Does this matter? I see you list <oldPk> in the query. After I get this working I will be able to create a PK

Comment: My goodness you are an SQL god.. my mind just exploded. I have no idea  what you did but its running. I wish I could understand this level of SQL. Going to check back in the morning. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that this is gonna be hella slow. =)

Comment: Thanks! It took 6 hours to run 60 millions rows but it's done

Comment: Should I create another question? I really want to learn a few things from this: Why do we do (1000000000 - 1), Why do we put a ';' before the statement and why is there a comma after we do 'SELECT *'.

Comment: @user1438150, Since `ROW_NUMBER` starts from `1`, we have to subtract `1` so that the new id will start from `PM1000000000`.

Comment: @user1438150, as for the semicolon `;` before the `WITH`, it is required that the statement before the `CTE` declaration, must be terminated by `;`. Some people prefer to begin their `CTE` declaration with `;`, instead of terminating the previous statement. But I suggest the latter.

Comment: @user1438150, comma `,` after `SELECT *`: column list in a `SELECT` statement must be separated by a `comma`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cursor.  It will be slow, though.  I've used cursors for datatables with ~1MM records, but not 60MM.  You can find an example of a cursor here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: In terms of speed how will this compared to wewesthemenace's answer?